# How Can I show the second array from string came from .split()

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this string

```
a = "This is just an example";
```

If I used

```
split(" ",1)
```

it will print the first word as an array.

My question is how can I split just the second string as an array?

Comment: Why do you want the element as an array instead of just a single string?

Answer (score 0):

Use a limit of 2, then slice starting from the second element.

```js
a = "This is just an example";
console.log(a.split(" ", 2).slice(1));
```

Or split the string with a limit of 2, then use an array literal containing just the second element.

```js
a = "This is just an example";
console.log([a.split(" ", 2)[1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Better Approach would be to split on a space & that will give you an array of string, select the index you want & split it further

Note : ARRAY INDEX STARTS FROM 0 NOT ONE, SO IF YOU WANT THE SECOND STRING, YOU WILL HAVE TO USE THE INDEX 1, NOT 2

```
const  a = "This is just an example";
const secondWordArr = a.split(' ')[1].split('');
// secondWordArr represents the array of characters of the seconds word
console.log(secondWordArr); // Output [ 'i', 's' ]
```

Explanation :

```
a.split(' ')  // this splits the string into an array of strings/words
a.split(' ')[1] // Access the second string in the array of split strings/words
a.split(' ')[1].split('') // splits the second string from the array of strings/words into a separate array//
```